# How do I receive the initial url and detect url changes in an Angular 4 app that does not use angular router to change the user interface?

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing

I am new to Angular and realized at an early stage that the routing Angular provides would not allow me the flexibility I needed for the UI in my app.

So I built a service that now handles the internal logic of the app as I want it. A typical button in the app would send some values to a function in my navigation controller (a service used in many components in the app).

this.navCtrlService.goTo({ title: 'item 1',..some params.., id: '11' });

This all works beautifully.

But.. It only works with navigation within the app. I would like to be able to detect a change in the url in the browser, parse the information and use it in my service.

1. Let's say the user access the site using the following:
   app.com/action-31231412
2. Something (router without an outlet?), detects the url and passes it along to the custom navigation service.
3. The navigation service uses "31231412" as it would have used the "id" from the button.

I'm stuck at step 2.

I've tried figuring out if I could use the router params in the Angular router, without much progress. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this that I'm not seeing.

Please note that what I'm asking for is a way to give my service access to changes in the url.